# I've been trying to open a jar file but every time I do so It tells this jar file could not be launched

Tags: macos, java, jar

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)
Joses-iMac-5:~ luissoto$ java -jar/Users/luissoto/Desktop/OptiFine_1.14.4_HD_U_F5.jar 
Unrecognized option: -jar/Users/luissoto/Desktop/OptiFine_1.14.4_HD_U_F5.jar
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Comment: You need a space after `-jar`

Answer (score 0):

#### Unrecognized option: -jar/Users/luissoto/Desktop/OptiFine_1.14.4_HD_U_F5.jar

You need a space after `-jar`:

```
java -jar /Users/luissoto/Desktop/OptiFine_1.14.4_HD_U_F5.jar
```

> Synopsis
>
> ```
> java [ options ] class [ arguments ]
>
> java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ arguments ]
>
> javaw [ options ] class [ arguments ]
>
> javaw [ options ] -jar file.jar [ arguments ]
> ```
>
> options
>
> Command-line options. See Options. class
>
> The name of the class to be called. file.jar
>
> The name of the JAR file to be called. Used only with the -jar command. arguments
>
> The arguments passed to the main function.

Source [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)